# Proving that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^a}>\frac{a}{1+a}, a>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

Binding an integral from one or both sides is always interesting even if the integral is doable.
For instance, $$a>0, x \in (0,1) \implies  1>1-x^{2a} \implies \frac{1}{1+x^a} > 1-x^a.$$
Hence $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^a}> \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^a)~ dx=\frac{a}{1+a}, a>0 ~~~(1)$$

The question is: How else (1) can be proved?

Comment: The bounds of $x$ are not working for your inequality. Let $x=0$, then $1 > 1 - 0^a$ ?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By cauchy schwarz $$\int_0^1 dx\le \sqrt{\int_0^1 (1+x^a)dx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^a}dx}$$ $$\Rightarrow\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^a} \ge \frac{a+1}{a+2}>\frac{a}{a+1}$$

Comment: You have got a better result!

Comment: @ZAhmed thanks a bit stronger infact

Answer (score 1):

We can know that
$$
\begin{align*}
1-\int_0^1{\frac{1}{1+x^a}\text{d}x}&=\int_0^1{\left( 1-\frac{1}{1+x^a} \right) \text{d}x}
\\
&=\int_0^1{\frac{x^a}{1+x^a}\text{d}x}
\\
&<\int_0^1{x^a\text{d}x}
\\
&=\frac{1}{a+1}
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore $\displaystyle \int_0^1{\frac{1}{1+x^a}\text{d}x}>\frac{a}{a+1}$.